# Measure Proof explanation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

For a measurable set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^d, \exists$ two open sets $A, B$ containing $F$ and $F^c$ $s. t.$

$$\mu(A-F) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$ \mu(B-F^c) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$\text{since} \  \ \ \ \ A \cap B \subset (A \cap F) \cup (B \cap F^c)$$

$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mu( A \cap B) \leq \mu(A \cap F) + \mu(B \cap F^c)$$

$$\text{How to get} \  \  \mu( A \cap B) \leq \mu(A - F) + \mu(B - F^c)$$

How did we jump between the last two lines?

Comment: You haven’t explained what your objective is.

Comment: @FShrike how did we jump between the last two lines?

Comment: Is the “since” line even correct?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, from set algebra. Page 18 in Halmos "Naive set theory". Which would work if we reverse $F$ and $F^c$ as Manifoldski did in his answer.

Comment: Think critically. $A\cap F = F$, etc., if I understood your set-up.

Comment: Oh, so it’s correct, but useless.

Comment: @TedShifrin exactly, using the complement of the complement is the way to go here due to the set-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sub-additivity and

$$A\cap B \subset (A \cap F^{c}) \cup (B\cap F) = (A - F) \cup (B-F^c)$$